# why doesn't it let me use the two variables outside of the db.collection?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, global

It does not let me read the two variables "titleNews" and "descriptionNews" from outside the db.collection and from within it does not add them to a RecyclerView. Can I create a global variable that I can read from outside?

```
private fun postToList(){
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        for (i:Int in 1..2){
            
            db.collection("news").document(i.toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it.exists()) {
                    //println("TITLE: ${it.getString("title").toString()}")
                    val titleNews = it.getString("title").toString()
                    val descriptionNews = it.getString("body").toString()
                }
            }
            titlesList.add(titleNews)
            descList.add(descriptionNews)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared them inside your if-statement block (between the `{` and `}` after `if`), so they are private to that block and are cleared from memory immediately at the `}` line. Local variables are only visible/usable from (i.e. "scoped" to) within the `{` and `}` they are declared in.

This can't work anyway, because the `onSuccessListener` is going to be called some time in the future, *after* the lines of code that you put under it. You need to put the code inside the if-statement, inside the listener block:

```
private fun postToList(){
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    for (i:Int in 1..2){
        
        db.collection("news").document(i.toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.exists()) {
                //println("TITLE: ${it.getString("title").toString()}")
                val titleNews = it.getString("title").toString()
                val descriptionNews = it.getString("body").toString()
                titlesList.add(titleNews)
                descList.add(descriptionNews)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put it inside it doesn't fill the RecyclerView

Comment: I don't see any code where you are doing anything with a RecyclerView, so I can't tell you what's going wrong there.